# Using multiple JavaScript files in a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm learning how to make Chrome extensions, but I'm having trouble figuring out what the best practices are to organize my code. In any other language, I know I would break down my codebase into multiple files and do imports, but when I had a file tree like this:

```
|
|-background.js
|-someotherfile.js
```

And someotherfile.js has a function like

```
export function somefunction(){alert("somefunction was called");}
```

But in background.js when I do

```
import * from 'someotherfile';
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    somefunction();
});
```

and I load my unpacked extension, background.js doesn't run, even though it does if I put somefunction in background.js.

What is the right practice for organizing my code in Chrome?

Comment: Chrome doesn't support dynamic loading of imports yet. You need to bundle it or use `require`-like solution. Or use a polyfill: [Which browsers support import and export syntax for ECMAScript 6?](//stackoverflow.com/q/33516906)

Comment: Bundle as in like have a Gulp task to concatenate all my JavaScript files into one background.js?

Comment: Yes. Or webpack and so on.

Comment: Or just list the other files in the manifest.

Comment: Thanks wOxxOm and Daniel!